# Authentication="Active Directory Integrated";` is trying to log to SQL Server as my computer instead of using my Active Directory account?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, azure-active-directory

Here's my connection string:

```
Data Source=myComputer;Initial Catalog=myDatabase;Persist Security Info=FalsePooling=False;
MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;
Authentication=\"Active Directory Integrated\";"
```

When I run the app from Visual Studio, I get the following error:

> Login failed for user: domain\myComputer.

`domain\myComputer` is not a login, I can't add it as new login as I am getting error `can't find the object`.

However, my Active Directory account is present in the SQL Server's `Security/Logins` nodes.

Why is `Authentication="Active Directory Integrated";` trying to log on to SQL Server as my computer instead of using my Active Directory account?

Thanks for helping

Comment: I thought you had to use `Integrated Security=True` instead of the `Authentication` setting.

Comment: Does it not have a `$` shown at the end of the login name? Computers *do* have accounts in AD, which is the machine name followed by a `$`. It would tend to indicate that your code is not running under *your* account but perhaps under a machine account such as "Network Service" - is it, perchance, ASP.Net code running under full IIS? If so, what application pool is it running under and what is the account for that application pool?

Comment: @jaunas, I've never used this type of connectionstring before, I try to connect from within Visual Studio. And going to the `advanced..` of the connection wizard, is where I saw what Visual Studio was trying to do.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I'm on my local and am using IIS express. the computer's name has `$` at the end, I just didn't want to write it here. Should I switch to using the full IIS?

Comment: `Integrated Security=True` is what I use to connect to SQL Server as the user which is running the SQL command.